# preventDefault (javascript) not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, checkout

I need help in javascript, my code in woocomerce (checkout) is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("billing_city").onkeyup = function validarDistrito(event){
    // do stuff
    var billinginfo = document.getElementsByName("billing_city")[0].value;
 var distritoArray= ["Barranco","Breña","Jesús María","La Victoria","Lince","Miraflores","Pueblo Libre","San Borja","San Isidro","San Luis","San Miguel","Surco","Surquillo","Callao","La Molina","Lima Cercado","Magdalena", "Rimac", "Lima Metropolitana"];
 
    console.log(billinginfo);
    for (i = 0; i < distritoArray.length; i++) {
        if(distritoArray[i].toUpperCase() == billinginfo.toUpperCase()){
            document.getElementById('payment_method_bacs').disabled = false;
            alert('igual');
        }else{
            document.getElementById('payment_method_bacs').disabled = true;
        }
     }
     event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

The code work very good, but then a few seconds later it updated and returns to a previous state. And I use the method preventDefault (); but it does not work in wordpress.

PD: the same holds true using jquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using e.preventDefault(); when it must be event.preventDefault();

take a look at validarDistrito(**event**), you named event the variable

try this code

```
<script>
document.getElementById("billing_city").onkeyup = function validarDistrito(event){
    // do stuff
    var billinginfo = document.getElementsByName("billing_city")[0].value;
    var distritoArray= ["Barranco","Breña","Jesús María","La Victoria","Lince","Miraflores","Pueblo Libre","San Borja","San Isidro","San Luis","San Miguel","Surco","Surquillo","Callao","La Molina","Lima Cercado","Magdalena", "Rimac", "Lima Metropolitana"];

    console.log(billinginfo);
    for (i = 0; i < distritoArray.length; i++) {
        if(distritoArray[i].toUpperCase() == billinginfo.toUpperCase()){
            document.getElementById('payment_method_bacs').disabled = false;
            return;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('payment_method_bacs').disabled = true;
        }
     }
     event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

the thing is that distroArray will keep validating the rest of it, so if the input value is equal to one of the values of the array, you need to stop validating

Comment: Thank you, I changed it, but still does not respond.

Comment: Thanks, but just it does not work, the problem is conflict with other javascript I think. I will use wordpress plugin last option.